# Creating a block from two wireframes

Tags: objects

I'm a very new Blender user (read: no experience).

I would like to create a block between two wireframes without losing the "texture" of the wireframes. A previous attempt using the Loft function was largely successful, but seemed to connect points from the bottom wireframe to points on the top wireframe.

Is there an easy process to create a block between two wireframes without having the wireframe points connect between layers.

Thank you for your help :)

EDIT: Currently I have three wireframes 'layers', I've sketched these out, but simplified them for the purpose of this question.

I would like to connect layer 1 and layer 2 to create one block, and also connect layer 3 and a *copy* of layer 2 to create a second block.

**EDIT 2:** Following Rick Riggs' animation, I was able to create this. This looks like what I am trying to do, but the object still has an internal structure. What I am trying to create is an object that has either no internal structure, or is solid, so that I am able to calculate a volume. My apologies for not being clearer, but this is very new territory for me. Thanks again for all your help :) [image]

Comment: Can you post an image of what you have, and an image of what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I've added a couple of diagrams which I hope will clear things up.

Comment: In the first sketch, 1 and 2 must belong to the same object, then enter *Edit Mode*, select the bounding edges of both and press `F` to create faces between them. For sketch two they must also belong to the same object, but it has to be a two step process, from 1 to 2 and then from 2 to 3, or vice-versa. For more detailed answers post screenshots of what you currently have in Blender and clarify if they are multiple objects or not.

Comment: I have posted an image of my current progress, I hope this helps clarify things a little.

Comment: Try again, but this time don't select any internal points, only perimeter points.

Answer (score -1):

This may be what you are looking for, if it is then I will circle back around to explain the details.

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful and I have been able to make progress. However I am still having a little bit of trouble with removing the structure within the object. Please see edits to post for clarification :)